# Alert a message when a specific option is selected without refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I want to alert that this is a square when the value of the option is square using ajax. But my problem is, when I enter the page and select square option, nothing happened and need to refresh to alert this is square.

This is my script that checks if square value is set so that ajax can process it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if($('#SelectBox').val() == 'square'){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'views/index/test',
        data:{},
        success:(function (response) {
            alert(response)
        })
    })
}
})
```

and this is my test.php

```
<?php echo "this is square"?>
```

and these are my tags

```
<select name="selected_option" id="SelectBox">
<option value="default" selected="selected">Select one option </option>
<option value="square">Square</option>
<option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That’s because you are checking the value only once on page load, but not after the user has actually changed it. Go read up how to use a change event handler in jQuery ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your check **once** on page load. Instead, hook up an event handler to the `change` event of the `select`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SelectBox').on("change", function() {         //****
        if ($('#SelectBox').val() == 'square') {      // Can use `$(this).val()` instead here
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'views/index/test',
                data: {},
                success: (function(response) {
                    alert(response)
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```